# Is it possible to order by a manual list

Tags: teradata

I am trying to create a query which groups payments into ranges (e.g. 4-, 5 - 9, 10 - 49, 50 - 99, 100 - 149, 150+).

If I try to order these by the above range they appear in alphabetical order (as you would expect).

Is it possible for me to order these by a manual list (see above range)

Comment: So you basically want to sort it as if that column were numeric?

Comment: Could you just order by the payment itself or is there a group by or something happening here?

Answer (score 2):

What's your TD release?

TD14 supports regular expressions, simply extract the first string of digits and cast it to an integer:

```
ORDER BY CAST(REGEXP_SUBSTR(grp, '[0-9]+') AS INTEGER)
```

Comment: I suck at regular expressions, and Teradata's [documentation](http://www.info.teradata.com/htmlpubs/DB_TTU_14_00/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1145_111A/Regular_Expr_Functions.085.01.html) of this function is confusing.  What does the `+` actually do?

Comment: It's looking for at least one occurrence of the previous expression, i.e. at least one digit. TD's docu on that topic is horrible, but there's a lot of online resources for regex :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [OTRANSLATE](http://www.info.teradata.com/htmlpubs/DB_TTU_14_00/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1145_111A/String_Ops_Funcs.084.173.html), which basically allows you to specify characters and replace them with another.

**EDIT :**  Thanks to JNeville for setting me straight on this being ranges.  The same idea still applies though, if you take his suggestion to make the last entry a range as well.
So, assuming you only have numbers, +, and -, and white space:

```
    select
     otranslate(<your column>,'+- ','')

    from
    <your table>
```

Which should return just the numeric portion of those strings.  Then you should be able to cast it as an integer, and sort it.

```
create volatile table vt as
(select cast ('-5' as varchar(10)) as theCol)
with data
on commit preserve rows;

INSERT into vt values ('10 - 49'); 

INSERT INTO vt values ('50 - 99');


insert into vt
values ('150-9999');



select
 cast (otranslate(theCol,'+- ','') as integer) as theNum
from
vt
order by theNum

    5
    1049
    5099
    1509999
```

Comment: Do an `INSERT into vt values ('10 - 49');` `INSERT INTO vt values ('50 - 99');` also and see if it sorts correctly. I'm guessing it won't. That being said, I like your answer. If I were OP, I would change that last `150+` to something like `150 - 99999` as a workaround and use your `OTRANSLATE()` suggestion. It's simple and painless.